# Is there a library which implements new Javascript/Ecmascript 5 methods for older versions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Although [Ecmascript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) introduces some completely new features, it also adds some new methods (bind, trim, map, etc.) which should be perfectly possible to implement (albeit slower) in current versions.  Does a library exist which implements these backwards compatible features (and no more, excluding Prototype et. al.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I just gave up and started an [ES5 library](http://bitbucket.org/JustinLove/es5/)

Comment: Looks interesting (you're missing `var` on L364 and L365).

Answer (score 11):

Kris Kowal and friends have built the es5-shim. It was part of Narwhal, but now lives on its own:

http://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/

Was: I've taken to using the global-es5.js shim from narwhal:

http://github.com/280north/narwhal/blob/master/engines/default/lib/global-es5.js

you'll have to take out the `require("json");` line at the bottom, but other than that, it should be browser-clean.

Comment: This is perfect. I was expecting the ECMAScript committee to have published something like this and for it to be easy to find... But this is the best I've found.

Answer (score 5):

[Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/) and [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) implement a lot of those.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [pulpjs](http://pulpjs.com/home/). You can pick the pieces you want to include, and then grab the [protocompat](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#3KKgw3xxQkA/trunk/js/incubator/pulp.protoCompat.js&q=protocompat%20package:http://pulpjs%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) module, which will make a bunch of methods available as extensions on the object prototypes.