# What modernizer scripts exist for the new ECMAScript 5 functions?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, backwards-compatibility, ecmascript-5

ECMAScript 5 has quite a few nice additions. [John Resig has a good overview here](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties). Here is a good [ECMAScript 5 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/).

A lot of this stuff can be "faked" for browsers that don't support these functions yet. Do you know of any scripts that can do this? I'm particularly interested in Object.create.

For example, [Douglas Crockford's JSON script](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) checks if JSON functions exist before creating them.

If there was more like the JSON one we could include them when we need to use the new functions.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890464/is-there-a-library-which-implements-new-javascript-ecmascript-5-methods-for-older/2916063#2916063

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Crockford recommends](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) this kind of `Object.create` shim:

```
if (typeof Object.create != "function") {
  Object.create = function (o) {
    function F(){}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F;
  };
}
```

But please **don't do this**.

The problem with this approach is that ES5 `Object.create` has a signature of **2 arguments**: first — an object to inherit from, and second (optional) — an object representing properties (or rather, descriptors) to add to newly created object.

```
Object.create(O[, Properties]); // see 15.2.3.5, ECMA-262 5th ed.
```

What we have is an **inconsistent implementation with 2 different behaviors**. In environments with native `Object.create`, method knows how to handle second argument; in environments without native `Object.create`, it doesn't.

What are the practical implications?

Well, if there's some code (say, a third party script) that wants to use `Object.create`, it's rather reasonable for that code to do this:

```
if (Object.create) {
  var child = Object.create(parent, properties);
}
```

— essentially assuming that if `Object.create` exists, it must conform to specs — accept second argument and add corresponding properties to an object.

But, with the above-mentioned shim, second argument is simply ignored. There's not even an indication of something going <del>wrong</del> differently. A silent failure, so to speak — something that's rather painful to detect and fix.

Can we do better?

Well, it's actually **impossible to create a fully-conforming `Object.create` shim using only (standard) ES3 facilities**. The best solution is to create a custom wrapper method.

There are, however, few alternative (less than optimal) things you can try:

1) Notify user about inability to work with second argument

```
if (!Object.create) {
  Object.create = function (o) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) { 
      throw Error('second argument is not supported'); 
    }
    // ... proceed ...
  };
}
```

2) Try to handle second argument:

```
if (!Object.create) {
  Object.create = function (parent, properties) {
    function F(){}
    F.prototype = parent;
    var obj = new F;
    if (properties) {
      // ... augment obj ...
    }
    return obj;
  }; 
}
```

Note that "properties" is an object representing **property descriptors**, not just property names/values, and is something that's not very trivial to support (some things are not even possible, such as controlling enumerability of a property):

```
Object.create(parent, {
  foo: {
    value: 'bar',
    writable: true
  },
  baz: {
    get: function(){ return 'baz getter'; },
    set: function(value){ return 'baz setter'; },
    enumerable: true
  }
});
```

The other inconsistency in the original shim is that it doesn't take care of **parent object being `null`**.

```
var foo = Object.create(null);
```

This creates an object whose [[Prototype]] is `null`; in other words, object that doesn't inherit from anything, not even `Object.prototype` (which all native objects in ECMAScript inherit from).

```
foo.toString; // undefined
foo.constructor; // undefined
// etc.
```

This is, by the way, useful to create "proper" hash tables in ECMAScript.

It's possible to emulate this behavior, but only using non-standard extensions, such as "magical"  `__proto__` property (so implementation would be not very portable or robust). Solution to this problem is similar: either emulate ES5 implementation fully, or notify about inconsistency/failure.

Comment: My [Xccessors JavaScript library](http://github.com/eligrey/Xccessors) provides `Object.defineProperty` and `Object.defineProperties` functions that you can use for solution #2.

Comment: That's very well spotted and your knowledge of ES5 is obviously solid but I think it's worth pointing out that Crockford's code predates ES5 by quite a while: first version circa 2006 and the latest, early 2008. So it's a little bit disingenuous to suggest that he 'recommends' this solution to shim over ES5.

Comment: Last time I've seen Doug talk about this shim was 3 months ago — http://www.slideshare.net/douglascrockford/javascript-the-good-parts-3292746/36 That's about 4 months after ES5 was officially standardized (in Dec 09) and is definitely later than 2008.

But I don't want to blame anyone (sorry if it came out that way). We all make mistakes. The idea is to recommend against **the approach** and explain why.

Comment: So do you recommend the solutions you mention here, or something else altogether?

Comment: @Bob Spryn, solutions #1 or #2 are both better than original one. You could also use different name for a method (e.g. `SomeLibrary.object.create`); as long as there's no inconsistent behavior across different environments.

Comment: At least we can do check `Object.create.length` to see if we're using the cheap shim instead of the real thing, if we actually need the 2nd argument.

Comment: "Notify user about inability to work with second argument", your #1 stratety, only happens for browsers that get the fallback. No user-defined `Object.create` fallback running under ES3 can conform to the ES5 spec. Please don't do it.

Comment: @Garrett That's why in my last paragraph there is: "It's possible to emulate this behavior, but only using non-standard extensions, such as "magical" \_\_proto__ property (so implementation would be not very portable or robust)". I explained pros and cons; I expect person to make reasonable decision based on that :)

Comment: @Garrett Edited to warn against using `Object.create` shims and creating wrapper instead. Left both versions as a demonstration of alternative (less than optimal) variations.

Answer (score 8):

es5-shim http://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/

This was part of the narwhal stand-alone javascript environment, but has been broken out on its own. It's pretty darn mature and precise.

Answer (score 3):

[es5 - JavaScript/EcmaScript 5 in 3](http://bitbucket.org/JustinLove/es5/src) is a collection shared at BitBucket. `Object.create` in particular is an easy one to *fake*, made popular [by Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) et al, but improved on here by [Justin Love](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30203/justin-love), focussing on many ES5 parts.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind learning the library and writing some code yourself, you can find some code implementations of the ECMAScript 5 library at

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JavaScript/ECMAScript_5_support_in_Mozilla

For example, the code for [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

And then Crockford has JSON.parse/stringify in json2.js

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js