# JavaScript prototyping: single prototype object or not?

Tags: javascript, oop, subclass

I don't really get JavaScript prototyping. Take this code, for instance:

```
function Class(asdf) {
 if(typeof(asdf) == 'undefined') {
 } else {
  this.asdf = asdf;
 }
}
Class.prototype.asdf = "default_asdf";
Class.prototype.asdf2 = [];
Class.prototype.change_asdf = function() {
 this.asdf = "changed_asdf";
 this.asdf2.push("changed_asdf2");
}

function SubClass() {
}
SubClass.prototype = new Class("proto_class");
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;

test1 = new SubClass();
alert("test1 asdf: " + test1.asdf + " " + test1.asdf2);
test1.change_asdf();
alert("test1 asdf: " + test1.asdf + " " + test1.asdf2);
test2 = new SubClass();
alert("test2 asdf: " + test2.asdf + " " + test2.asdf2);
```

The first alert prints "proto_class []", as expected. The second alert prints "changed_asdf [changed_asdf2]", also as expected. But why does the third alert print "proto_class [changed_asdf2]"?! If the original prototype object (new Class("proto_class")) is being modified, then why doesn't the asdf variable remain "changed_asdf"? And if it isn't, then why does the asdf2 array contain "changed_asdf2"? Furthermore, how do I make sure that each new SubClass() instance contains a fresh instance of Class(), as in C++ and Java?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you write

```
SubClass.prototype = new Class("proto_class");
```

you are creating a prototype of **one instance** of `Class`. What you want is to create a sub-class that inherits from its parent's prototype. As David Flanagan shows in his [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002AWX8CI) (§ 9.5), you have to use a helper function to create a new object with a specified prototype:

```
function heir(p) {
    function f(){}         // dummy constructor function
    f.prototype = p;       // specify prototype object we want
    return new f();        // create and return new object
}
```

(Crockford calls this function `Object.create`, after the so-called [ES5 object constructor property](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.2.3.5), but please don't do this, as this [can be misleading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075308/what-modernizer-scripts-exist-for-the-new-ecmascript-5-functions/3075818#3075818).)

Within the SubClass constructor, you have to [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) the Class constructor with `this` set to the current object:

```
function SubClass() {
    // call the parent's constructor with
    // `this` set to the current scope
    Class.call(this, "proto_class");
}
```

And last, but not least, you only reset `Class.asdf2` once, but not in the constructor function of `Class` or `SubClass`. So add `this.asdf2 = [];` to one of the constructors.

The complete code now reads:

```
function heir(p) {
    function f(){}         // dummy constructor function
    f.prototype = p;       // specify prototype object we want
    return new f();        // create and return new object
}

function Class(asdf) {
    if (typeof asdf != 'undefined')
        this.asdf = asdf;
}

Class.prototype.asdf = "default_asdf";
Class.prototype.asdf2 = [];
Class.prototype.change_asdf = function() {
    this.asdf = "changed_asdf";
    this.asdf2.push("changed_asdf2");
}

function SubClass() {
    // call the parent's constructor with
    // `this` set to the current scope
    Class.call(this, "proto_class");
    this.asdf2 = [];
}

SubClass.prototype = heir(Class.prototype);
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;

test1 = new SubClass();
alert("test1 asdf: " + test1.asdf + " " + test1.asdf2);
test1.change_asdf();
alert("test1 asdf: " + test1.asdf + " " + test1.asdf2);
test2 = new SubClass();
alert("test2 asdf: " + test2.asdf + " " + test2.asdf2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `asdf2` is a mutable array on `Class.prototype`. That array is shared by all instances that delegate to that prototype. If you want each instance to have a separate `asdf2`, you have to assign it to `this.asdf2` in some method.

Note that you assign `this.asdf`, but you never assign `this.asdf2`, you just push on to the existing array.

```
var house = {nice: true};
var me = {home: house};
var roomie = {home: house};

// Now roomie has a party and trashes the place.
roomie.home.nice = false;

//and how's my house?
me.home.nice === false;
// because house is shared.
```

The sharing of `house` in this example is the same as the sharing of `asdf2` in the question.