# standard javascript tweaks

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Hi so I'm finding that often want to include some or all of the following in my js projects:

- Crockford's Object.create
- Array.prototype.indexOf
- Array.prototype.remove
- Crockford's json2.js

see full example file @ https://gist.github.com/752895

so the question(s) .... what am I missing? Is there a better way to achieve this?

( I also use jquery, does it already address some of these issues? )

Comment: **Off-topic**: You might also look at the non-`eval` versions of JSON2 that Crockford has on [his github page](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). (There are two, one a  state machine, the other a recursive-descent parser.) The basic json2.js still uses `eval`, although it takes precautions first, which means in theory it could still be defeated.

Comment: BTW: why not to use crockford's Object.create as is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075308/what-modernizer-scripts-exist-for-the-new-ecmascript-5-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a few functions like [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), which works like `Array.prototype.indexOf()` and [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), which works like `JSON.parse()` but it doesn't have an equivalent for stringifying JSON or removing elements from an array (to my knowledge).  jQuery maps to the native methods if they are available.

You might want to check out [Kris Kowal's ECMAScript 5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js) and see if there any other methods you might need that have native equivalents in modern browsers.  This gives you the best of both worlds - compatibility in older browsers and better performance in newer ones.

Comment: excellent thanks! - covers everything on my list (apart from json2) + a load more goodness ;) ..i just found this also: https://github.com/eligrey/Xccessors

Comment: @zack: that's pretty cool too. It's a shame older Internet Explorers don't support accessor methods, they're incredibly useful.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to achieve this?

Not really. jQuery is intentionally hands-off things like the `Array.prototype`, hence your having to add your own `indexOf` and `remove` on browsers that don't have them. Evetually most of these will be directly supported by browsers as they upgrade their engines to ECMAScript 5th edition; until then, we have to upgrade the current set ourselves. Just make sure your script is clean, combine it with other scripts in your application as part of a build process (so you don't have lots of different source files), and go to town. (Edit: Sorry, you clearly already undestand that latter point, as you've folded json2.js into your script.)

Comment: Why is that? Wouldn't it be convenient to have all that kind of functionality in a framework?

Comment: @sjngm: Sure it would. And in fact, [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) has a lot of that. I didn't get the impression he was asking for a framework. He's already *got* these implementations, in his own mini-framework.

Comment: The developer should be in charge of which prototypes get enhanced, not the framework or library. Because these so-called enhancements might generate conflicts if different frameworks are used.

Comment: @tjcrowder : no indeed, not looking for another framework .. but thinking about whether it would be good to build up a 'js boilerplate' file with a bunch of this kind of stuff... - to used with care as Jan points out!

Answer (score 0):

You might find it worth your while to learn to use a module loader such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). This will make it tad easier for you to manage your dependencies. There are some [basic instructions available](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) in case you want to look at it.

As an additional benefit the loader makes it possible for you to minify your code via Google Compiler. Also [the module pattern](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define) the loader uses is quite nifty.

Comment: I don't think it makes any sense at all to use RequireJS for things like adding `Array.prototype.indexOf` and such. The code involved in adding those is tiny; the cost involved in a module loader (at least for something used on the web as opposed to intranets) is very high (extra HTTP GET).

Comment: Interesting point. I guess there must be some cut-off point for that. At least development-wise it's a fun library to use. :)